# if a character is a digit between 0 and 8 then increase it by 1 (others characters are unchanged)

Tags: java, string, replace

```
public String f2(String string) {
    String result = "";
    String num = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(string.charAt(i) + "");
                if (number > 0 || number < 8) {
                    number += 1;
                    num = String.valueOf(number);
                }
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Example of input:

```
123abc
```

Expected output:

```
234abc
```

I solved the increase in the value of the character by 1 unit if it was a number, but I haven't solved the problem of putting the characters together.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Instead of ```num = String.valueOf(number)``` replace it by ```num += String.valueOf(number) ``` and then return num

Comment: nope, I wan't return 234abc, not 234 

Comment: O right, so in that case if  ```if(!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i)))```, do ```result += string.charAt(i);```, and finally, prepend num to result

Comment: if I input: 1a2b3c => the result must be 2a3b4c 

Comment: True, so the solution I gave you is for the easy case, for the case you are posing you can start off from mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed appending the values to `result`. You need to append the incremented digit or the character as it is (if it is not in the range of `0 - 8`) to `result` as shown below:

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(f2("123abc"));

    }

    public static String f2(String string) {
        String result = "";
        String num = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(string.charAt(i) + "");
                if (number > 0 || number < 8) {
                    number += 1;
                    num = String.valueOf(number);
                    result += num;// Add it here
                }
            } else {// Add it here
                result += string.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
234abc
```

Answer (score 2):

First, a general note about your solution - `char`s can be comapred directly with the `<` and `>` operators, as well as incremented, so you don't need to go through the conversion of a specific character to an `int`.

With regard to collecting the modified characters, yhe easiest approach would probably be to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static String f2(String string) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = string.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '8') {
            ch++;
        }
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. But I am still trying to solve it with my code 

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, I have arrived to that solution:

```java
public String f2(String string) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(string.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        char c = string.charAt(i);
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '8') {
            result.append(++c);
        } else {
            result.append(string.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

As you can see I check whether is a valid character (in your case a number between 0-8), and if it is I append the successor of it to `result`, in case not I just simply append it to `result`.
So now it works for `123abc` case and `1e3f4t5z` case too.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 (or above), you can do like below:

```
public String f2(String string) {

    return string.codePoints()
            .map(ch -> (ch >= '0' && ch <= '8') ? ch + 1 : ch)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                     StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
                     StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Digits from `0` to `8` in the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) characters table have decimal codes from `48` to `56`. Each character in `Java` has its own decimal code. The `String` class has the *old* [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method, which replaces all occurrences of a single character with another character. The simplest way here is to use a reverse loop:

```java
String string = "abcdefghi.. 0123456789 003";
String string2 = string;

for (int i = 56; i > 47; i--) {
    string2 = string2.replace((char) i, (char) (i + 1));
}

System.out.println(string);  // abcdefghi.. 0123456789 003
System.out.println(string2); // abcdefghi.. 1234567899 114
```